# Autoconf x86 cross-compiling

Tags: c, cross-compiling, autotools, autoconf

AutoConf has `--host` option to specify an architecture the file will be run on. But if I specify `--host=i686-linux-gnu`, no option `-m32` is added to `gcc` compiler. What did I understand wrong about AutoConf? Because in this case, if I compile my program on 64 bit machine, it won't run on host machine.

Comment: x32 is not i386/32-bit x86, so I think the subject line of your question is asking something different from what you mean to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing `--host=i686-linux-gnu` will cause autoconf to look for and use `i686-linux-gnu-gcc`, etc. rather than `gcc`. This is expected to be a cross toolchain that produces 32-bit binaries. If you don't want to use a cross toolchain but just `-m32`, you should just pass `CC="gcc -m32"` (and `CXX="g++ -m32"` if the program uses C++) to configure.